# Fargate - How do I make an API call to another container within the same task definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

When developing locally, I run `docker-compose`, where I have two services Service1 and Service2. Service2 depends on Service1. When I deploy them to ECS, I create them within one task definition and provide JSON array of container definitions to spin them up.

When I run them locally, within docker-compose, from Service2 I can call http://Service1:8080/v1/graphql (since they're in docker-compose together I can call it by the service name) ... however, when I deploy to ECS and I make that same API call, I get a 404.

Based on this: [Docker links with awsvpc network mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772120/docker-links-with-awsvpc-network-mode) I've also tried http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql ... I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: "I've also tried http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql" and what happens? Any errors, timeouts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58196930/communication-between-containers-in-ecs-task-definition

Answer (score 0):

I'd try [service discovery](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecs-service-discovery/) as [mentioned here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-tasks-services-communication/):

> Amazon ECS now includes integrated service discovery. This makes it possible for an ECS service to automatically register itself with a predictable and friendly DNS name in Amazon Route 53. As your services scale up or down in response to load or container health, the Route 53 hosted zone is kept up to date, allowing other services to lookup where they need to make connections based on the state of each service.

See [an example here](https://github.com/ranman/ecs-service-discovery-demo).